# How to update WordPress wp_usermeta?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I need to update a single column in  wordpress `wp_usermeta`.I have gone through the web and I found these codes

```
<?php update_user_meta( $user_id, $meta_key, $meta_value, $prev_value ); ?>
```

Here 
    user_id=1, meta_key=first_name, meta_value="Smith", $prev_value="benny"

How do i write SQL to update the specific column.

Comment: Is this question 'fixed' as you said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51280509/how-to-use-mysql-select-query-in-word-press-user-meta-data-and-left-join-from-ot?noredirect=1#comment89540452_51280509)? If so, please accept an answer (of add your own answer).

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to write the SQL, wp gives you that function.

If you are doing a one-off to update the DB, then in your phpmyadmin, you just find the record, and edit it manually;

if writing PHP, then you use

`update_user_meta( $user_id, $meta_key, $meta_value, $prev_value )`

ie update_user_meta( 1, 'first_name', 'Smith', 'benny' )

Comment: If you really want the SQL, then it would something like UPDATE `wp_usermeta` SET `meta_value`='Smith' WHERE `user_id`='1' AND `meta_key`='first_name' AND `meta_value`='benny';

Answer (score 1):

Use below code to update user meta value if it match old meta value

```
$user_id = 1;
$meta_key = 'first_name';
$new_value = 'Smith';
$prev_value = 'benny';


update_user_meta( $user_id, $meta_key, $new_value, $prev_value );
```