# How to use MySQL select query in word press user meta data and left join from other table?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I need to get the user count if he is active.

I have two table:

1. users
2. wp_user_meta

In a `wp_user_meta` table the some details of user are stored in serialised form there were the user `active_status` is.

how do I write a query to get user count  with above conditions

I used to get user meta using wordpress method

**Like:**

```
$user_meta = get_user_meta( 98 );

$all=$user_meta['coupon_user_meta'][0];

$unser=unserialize($all);

print_r($unser);
```

and the output is

```
Array ( [active_status] => active [subscribe] => yes [avatar] => [confirmation_hash] => )
```

how to write query?

Thank you all lastly i have hard-coded some. its works for me.
please review this code.

```
$data = array();
$results = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM wp_users");

if(!empty($results)){

    foreach($results as $row){
        $person_id= $row->ID;
        $data[] = person_id;
    }
}
$num=0;
$check=$meta=$unserial=NULL;
foreach($data as $user){

    $check=get_user_meta($user);
    $meta=$check['coupon_user_meta'][0];


$unserial=unserialize($meta);


$co=$unserial['active_status'];


    if($co=="active"){
        $num++;

    }


}
echo $num;
```

Comment: You didn't accept one of the answers on your previous questions. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51016324/how-to-update-wordpress-wp-usermeta) is very similar to this question. Please respond to your other questions before asking new questions.

Comment: Is it dynamic user id or do you want to get all user meta data? For the count, you can use sizeof() funtion

Comment: @StephanVierkant  Sorry bro its my mistake that was fixed.but i need to fetch the data do you have any idea

Comment: @SuYatanar is i need number of users with their status is active as said above

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```html
select sum(um.meta_value = '1') Sex1, sum(um.meta_value = '2') Sex2
from wp_usermeta um
join wp_users u on u.id = um.user_id
where um.meta_value = 1
group by date(u.user_registered)
```

Thanks!!

Comment: thanks for the reply  ,But in the wp_user_meta table the data are in a serialized form how do i give a condition in a query

Answer (score 0):

Try with this code.

```
<?php
$allusers = get_users( $args = array() );
foreach ( $allusers as $user ) {
   if($user->active_status == 'active'){
    $active_user[] = $user->active_status;
   }
}

$count = sizeof($active_user);
?>
```

Comment: thanks bro i got some idea . I will first fetch the data from wp_user_meta and un serialize the data of active users ,then i store the data in an array ,then i use the array find the number of users on other table ..thanks

Comment: Great!! Haha. I'm not bro. I'm sis. Try it. If you get answer, please update on this page. :-)